# SignalR Hub close cause client freez

Tags: vb.net, signalr

I'm connecting to SignalR hub from VB.NET client app. When I close the connection to the hub inside FormClosing of the main form, the application freeze for some seconds.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through that annoying bug. A workaround is to close the connection in a new thread. (this is C# as I don´t know Visual Basic)

```
// connection disposing can block the UI thread for about 20 seconds

Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        connectionToDispose.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Will that prevent the Application from exit until the task is finished?

Comment: I don´t think so

Comment: Are you closing the connection just before the app exists? If that´s the case, I don´t you need that step. The server should close the connection automatically when a client does not send pings for a while.